# How to get bitmap of image from url

Tags: android-studio

I want to load image from url and then convert it Bitmap.

```
objecturl.getString("imageurl");
```

and want to show it in imagview and then convert it into bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step Sync gradle of Picasso to load image fro url.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Second load image using picasso

```
String imgurl = objecturl.getString("imageurl");
Picasso.get().load(imgurl).into(imageView); //image will load successfully
```

Third use bitmap to convert image into bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```